# Why Javascript constructor doesn't return

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

I have a problem.
When i instance from a object it doesn't return value of constructor.
................................................................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................................................................

```js
//Main Branch
var Creatures = function () {
    function Creatures(name,alive) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
    }
    function Creatuers(name,alive,sleep) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }
};

var Beast = function () {
    function breathe() {
        return true;
    }
    this.__proto__ = new Creatures;
};
var Mammals = function () {
    this.numberOfBeads = "i am numberOfBeads from Mammals";
    this.__proto__ = new Beast;
};


//Mammals Branch
var Humans = function () {
    function thinking(){
        return true;
    }
    this.love = "i am love from humans";
    this.__proto__ = new Mammals;
};
var Animals = function () {
    this.instinct = "i am Animals from Animals";
    this.__proto__ = new Mammals;
};
var Plants = function () {
    this.color = "i am color from Plants";
    function grown() {
        return true;
    }
    this.__proto__ = new Creatures;
};
var Trees = function () {
    this.height = "i am height from Trees";
    this.__proto__ = new Plants;
};
var Flowers = function () {
    this.smell = "i am smell from Flowers";
    this.__proto__ = new Plants;
};
var Grasses = function () {
    this.color = "i am color from Grasses";
    this.__proto__ = new Plants;
};
var obj2 = new Creatures("ali",true);
alert(obj2.name);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="sampleObject1.js"></script>
<script src="sampleObject2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you try to do is obscure. Can you explain your intent (and reduce your code to a [mcve] ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to 
`var obj2 = new Creatures("ali",true);` it **does** return an instance! It does not return new Creatures instance with properties `name` and `alive` as these are not parameters of you constructor function, nor they are properties set in your constructor function (*top-level one*):

```
var Creatures = function () {
    ...
};
```

what it seems you are trying to do is to create overloaded constructor?! 
Function overloading is not supported in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm as @Denys Seguret said, certain things seems rather obscure...

Anyway, you get undefined because a function constructor return an object with the properties that you attach in that function constructor.

In your case, your function is:

```
var Creatures = function () {
    function Creatures(name,alive) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
    }
    function Creatures(name,alive,sleep) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }
};
```

This is a function expression that has inside it's scope two functions with the same name (the second one will override the first, though the first it's useless).

As you can see, you are not setting any kind of property to the object that will be implicitly returned from it.

I make your example to work just replacing it with the second function declaration:

```js
function Creatures(name,alive,sleep) {
  this.name = name;
  this.alive = alive;
  this.sleep = sleep;
}

var obj2 = new Creatures("ali", true);
alert(obj2.name);
```

This make an alert that says "ali".

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any return statement in the function

```
var Creatures = function () {
    function Creatures(name,alive) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
    }
    function Creatuers(name,alive,sleep) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }
};
```

what you're probably trying to do is delegate the instantiation of the object choosing the proper constructor based on the parameters (and maybe some business logic). watch out that there is no method overloading in javascript so you need to use different naming for the inner functions.

```js
var Creatures = function (...params) {
    function Creatures1(name,alive) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
    }
    function Creatures2(name,alive,sleep) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alive = alive;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }
    return params.length === 2 ? new Creatures1(...params) : new Creatures2(...params);
};

var obj2 = Creatures("ali",true);
alert(obj2.name);
```